# BST tree - dictionary in Java

Tags: java, implementation, binary-search-tree

Does anyone would tell me if there's somewhere an implementation of using binary trees with creating a dictionary in Java ?

Comment: look at [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: why binary tree specifically?what about hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the `TreeMap` class does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could use TreeMap class.

Documentation says it's implemented with Red black trees.

> A red-black tree is a binary search tree where each node has a color
>   attribute, the value of which is either red or black. In addition to
>   the ordinary requirements imposed on binary search trees, the
>   following additional requirements apply to red-black trees

If you want to know more, check out the source.

Comment: Do you know if there's somewhere "Ready implemented" code... ?

Comment: TreeMap is ready implemented. You can use it by importing java.util

Comment: Do you mean something else?